# Angular 8 need slider charts and graphs

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, graph, charts

I am new on angular and stuck with the some rare kind of graphs.

Need some library to draw the following graph

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can use [d3.js](https://d3js.org). It is a complete library to draw your graphs

Comment: Hi Troopers, thanks for reply.... I didn't find the related graph in this library...is there any library??

Comment: If you don't find a similar graph, you can draw your graph with svg elements : d3.js allows to draw svg